# how to fix "Unknown URL content://com.new.newapp.locations/locations" in android studio

Tags: android

This is the error I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL  content://com.new.newapp.locations/locations
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1213)
        at com.new.newapp.activity.FragmentGoogleMap$LocationInsertTask.doInBackground(FragmentGoogleMap.java:364)
        at com.new.newapp.activity.FragmentGoogleMap$LocationInsertTask.doInBackground(FragmentGoogleMap.java:360)
```

And I have researched this problem and found these similar questions:
    [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175716/illegalargumentexception-unknown-url-content-content)
    [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551428/android-contentprovider-uri-issue-unknown-url-content)
    [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208223/error-in-insert-data-in-own-content-provider)

And non of these helped.  What bugs me a lot is that when I was using eclipse I didn't have this issue, but since working on Android Studio I can't seem to get this working.

in my `LocationsContentProvider` class:

```
package com.new.newapp.activity;

public class LocationsContentProvider extends ContentProvider{

public static final String PROVIDER_NAME ="com.new.newapp.activtiy.locations";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/locations" );
private static final int LOCATIONS = 1;
private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher ;

static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "locations", LOCATIONS);
}

LocationsDB mLocationsDB;
```

And in my manifest I have this:

```
</activity>

    <provider
        android:name="com.new.newapp.activity.LocationsContentProvider"
        android:authorities="locations"
        android:exported="false" />

</application>
```

I have tried `android:authorities="com.new.newapp.activity.locations"` 
I have also tried `android:name=".LocationsContentProvider"
Have also moved`

Could some one please help?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in provider name.

```
<provider
        android:name="com.new.newapp.activity.LocationsContentProvider"
        android:authorities="locations"
        android:exported="false" />

public static final String PROVIDER_NAME ="com.new.newapp.activtiy.locations";
```

it should be

```
public static final String PROVIDER_NAME ="com.new.newapp.activity.LocationsContentProvider";
```